# Remove URL and add hashtag to wp_list_categories (WordPress)

Tags: wordpress, wp-list-categories

Currently my menu-navigation in WordPress looks like this:

```
<ul>

<li class="cat-item cat-item-1">
<a href="http://website/food/pizza/">Pizza</a>
</li>

<li class="cat-item cat-item-3">
<a href="http://website/food/snacks/">Snacks</a>
</li>

</ul>
```

Is there any posibility to add some code to functions.php, so I will get this?:
(remove "http://website/food/", then add # before slug)

```
<ul>

<li class="cat-item cat-item-1">
<a href="#pizza">Pizza</a>
</li>

<li class="cat-item cat-item-3">
<a href="#snacks">Snacks</a>
</li>

</ul>
```

I tried some code with:

```
add_filter( 'wp_list_categories', 'filter_categories' );

function filter_categories( $html ) {
  ...preg_replace...
}
```

But with no luck...

Can someone please help me out?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
  <?php
  foreach (get_categories() as $category){
    echo '<li class="cat-item">';
    echo '<a href="#'.$category->name.'">';
    echo $category->name;
    echo '</a></li>';
  } ?>
```

Comment: where do I have to put this code? just in functions.php?

Comment: Wherever you're listing your categories.

Comment: Is there really no posibility to do this in functions.php? with wp_list_categories?

Comment: Not without creating a new function. `wp_list_categories` is a default function which accepts arguments, to call it in functions will just display the default arguments.

Answer (score 0):

change in word press admin menu screen for change category in menu item to custom link where you can set target URL accordingly.

Answer (score -1):

you got a plugin for this : Page Links To. You make a fake page, at the bottom of the page, you can set its link (so here : #pizza), and then add it to the menu as you do for a normal page